# Why are priests fighting in this temple?

Tags: temple, brahmins, war

https://youtu.be/tvKcoiYglDM

Someone forwarded me this video and I can't tell why the brahmin priests are quarrelling with each other, that too in a place of worship.

Anyone knows what led to the disagreement? Do these priests belong to rival sects or something?

Comment: Not relevant question here.